# What does this {0}:{1} mean in lua?

Tags: lua, fivem

I have a script in Lua tha is using an export, the problem is that the export returns this {0}:{1} inside a Success variable.How can I compare this in an if statement? I mean
that I have this line of code :

```
TriggerEvent('chatMessage',Success) -- Prints the {0}:{1}
if Success = ? -- What am i suposed to compare it with to go 
                  inside the if?
```

Note that i am new to Lua.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: printing `{0}:{1}` is not a lot of information to go on, my guess is that is just a string so compare it to `"{0}:{1}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I passed the Success variable into a 2nd variable and printed it out. Turns out that it was a boolean all the time. But for some reaseon it couldn't compare it inside the if. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Lua can't pass simple values by reference, so if `Success` is a string, then `TriggerEvent` function can't change `Success` value, so you probably misinterpreted the documentation. According to the [documentation](https://docs.fivem.net/docs/scripting-manual/working-with-events/triggering-events/), TriggerEvent accepts parameters where the `Success` variable is.